# Auto select shipping method on paypal review page

Tags: magento2

How can I auto select shipping method on page load for PayPal review page?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever find a creative solution to this problem? I'm on the newest version of the paypal module and STILL you have to choose a shipping method from the dropdown, even if there is only one option. It's causing a lot of confusion with my customers.